# displaying on line users(active users) in my web page asp.net(c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my website login id and pass word for each users
For displaying online users i use Global.asax file

In Global.asax there is

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
}
```

In appliction startup i want to store each logged in users to an arry 
and logout time i want to remove from array..

how can i implement this with my project?

Comment: please dont abuse the code tag

Answer (score 0):

You should use **Session_Start** to add user and **Session_End** to remove user from static array or **Application["UsersOnline"]** storage.

Comment: how can i declare an dynamic array with two fielda userid,time

Comment: Is I understand correctly you need to store somwhere your data. 1, you can get helper class with static `Dictionary<int, DateTime>`. Second, you can get singleton class for the same porposes. And last thing you can store your `Dictionary<int, DateTime>` in the Application like I described above (even can write an extension method for fast retriewing).

Comment: am not aware of this Dictionary<int, DateTime>,ccan u give other link for checking other program for how to use this

Comment: it's a lot of articles exists. Here is one of them: [Online active users counter in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Online-Active-Users.aspx)